# assign_attributes and save later in loop - ruby rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I want to `assign_attribute` to various rows in a table and then save them together in a loop. So here is how I am trying to do,

```
player_arr = []
params[:player_types].each do |index,p_type_params|
  if p_type_params[:id]
    player_arr << @player_types.find(p_type_params[:id]).assign_attributes(p_type_params)
  end
end
```

Later I wish to do a save atomically on all the updates as a transaction,

```
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
   player_arr.each do |p_type|
     p_type.save
   end
end
```

But this does not seem to work as p_type seems to be  NilClass. I dont understand why because when I do player_arr.length I get a positive number. 
Also the goal here is to capture all the assignment errors in the first loop and then do an atomic save. Ofcourse I can save in the first loop itself but it will capture only the first encountered error. Any pointers will be really helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you are doing too much in one line.

```
player_arr << @player_types.find(p_type_params[:id]).assign_attributes(p_type_params)
```

Here you are adding the return value of `assign_attributes` (`nil`) to the `player_arr` array.

Do this instead:

```
player_arr = []
params[:player_types].each do |index,p_type_params|
  if p_type_params[:id]
    player = @player_types.find(p_type_params[:id])
    player.assign_attributes(p_type_params)
    player_arr << player
  end
end
```

Comment: Although this works fine, I use @player_types in my view to display errors.full_messages(). Doing this way `@player_types` does not retain any error information that would have occured while assigning